# What's the maximum number of listeners an Oracle database can have?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

Can an Oracle database have more than one listener? If so, what's the maximum number of listeners a database can have?

Comment: Did you read the docs?http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/network.920/a96580/listener.htm

Comment: Thanks Mat, I didn't but now I'm gonna..

Comment: There is no practical limit to the number of listeners, as far as I know. I can't imagine a use case for more than a handful of listeners, though.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no limit.  Of course, it is exceptionally rare that you would have more than one listener for a database.  I've seem people run two listeners just in case one listener fails but I've never heard of anyone wanting to run more than two.  If you really wanted to, though, nothing stops you from running a dozen listeners on a dozen different ports or on a dozen different machines.  But since the listener is virtually never the bottleneck and the listener virtually never fails, that sort of redundancy is rarely helpful.

Comment: Having more than one listener (local+remotes) is not rare for RAC configurations.

Comment: Running multiple listeners is quite common in complex networks or complex solutions. You may have listeners for different client classes, different networks, scan listener, virtual ip listeners etc.